# How to replace strings in list from a dictionary wtith just 1 desired output

Tags: python, list

I want to replace a string named `test1` which is listed in `lst` using a dictionary named `gRep1Map`. It needs to return the raw string and the word variant using the characters in `gRep1Map`. Can't really seem to find a way how to achieve this.

Here is my code.

```
gReplMap = { 'a': '@', 'e': '3', 'i': '1', 'o': '0', 't': '+',
         'A': '@', 'E': '3', 'I': '1', 'O': '0', 'T': '+' } 

m = str.maketrans(gReplMap)

lst = ['test1']
# ??
lst = [ pswd.translate(m) ]
if pswd not in lst: lst.append(pswd):
# ??
print(lst)
```

The desired output should be like this.

```
 ['test1', '+3s+1']
```

Anyone who could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this :

```
lst = ['test1', 'test1'.translate(m)]
print(lst)
```

Output is:

```
['test1', '+3s+1']
```